# Подключение к БД в mysql более 1 сек + сразу решение (PHP, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

Значит так, ребятки... Я задал этот вопрос, но уже знаю на него ответ. А задал я его для того, что бы такие как я, не сидели миллион лет и не гуглили в чем проблема долгого вывода данных на localhost.

**Смысл вопроса:**

Я сидел и гуглил около 3х дней, что бы решить эту проблему. Проблема заключается в том, что сам `Запрос` в mysql занял - `0,0004 сек.`, а сам проект, когда я его запускаю по запросу `localhost/` отображается `3,0004 сек.` (3 секунды а не 4 тысячных миллисекунды).

Я пользуюсь `openserver` и ORM `RedBeanPHP`.

Вот мой прошлый скрипт подключения к `mysql`:

```
R::setup( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbr',
        'root', '' );
```

Comment: ответ надо писать в ответе....в вопросе описание вопроса и вопрос..........вся лирика о том, как зараждалась жизнь - не нужна

Comment: Лирику написал, для того что бы каждый мог понять конкретно его ли это решение, и его ли это проблема. А ответ чуть позже продублирую и в вопросе его уберу!

Comment: то есть это: "Значит так, ребятки... Я задал этот вопрос, но уже знаю на него ответ. А задал я его для того, что бы такие как я, не сидели миллион лет и не гуглили в чем проблема"  или вот это:  "Я сидел и гуглил около 3х дней, что бы решить эту проблему." ---даёт каждому понимание **конкретно его ли это решение, и его ли это проблем**?

Comment: Для опытного человека, это вступление дает понимание того, что эта проблема может быть настолько сложной, насколько ему бы это не показалось сложным. А для людей, которые попали в такое же положение как и я - ностальгию, и похожую ситуацию (а когда люди видят похожую ситуацию, их это начинает больше всего завлекать)

Comment: Этот текст давит на человеческое мышление, даже вы из-за него сейчас со мной ведете довольно долгую беседу)))

Comment: Я обращаю внимание, что полезной нагрузки в нём НОЛЬ. И надеюсь вы, как здравомыслящий, всё же поймёте это....а может нет...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Решение этой ужасной задержки в 3 секунды:**

Как вы заметили ранее, я подключался так - `host=localhost`
Оказывается, mysql не может сразу отдавать данные на этот "домен"
Вам надо подключаться так - `host=127.0.0.1` - то есть подключаться к ip 127.0.0.1
Тем самым, mysql изначально отдает данные на этот ip, и из-за этого не будет никакой задержки, не считая время запроса, в моем случае `0,0004 сек.`

Ну и еще, вам надо сделать `АЛИАС` с исходного домена `127.0.0.1` на папку проекта `localhost` (ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО переименуйте папку своего проекта на `localhost` - это связано не только с этим случаем а еще и со всякими правилами самого `openserver`).
Делается это очень просто! Переходите в `Настройки` openserver, Выбираете раздел `Алиасы`, ставите всё так, как я указал выше, и перезапускаете openserver. Поздравляю, теперь у когда вы будете переходить по домену `127.0.0.1`, у вас не будет никакой задержки!